# Correct behaviour of Mouse down inside row of NSTableView?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstableview, nsview, nsimageview

I have a NStableView which is NSView based. In each row also have a NSImageView which is subview of NSView. I have subclassed this NSImageView then overrided **mouseDown** method. The problem is **tableViewSelectionDidChange** is also getting fired when user clicks on this imageview. I want only **mouseDown** to be called but not tableViewSelectionDidChange.

If I set **selectionHighlightStyle** of table to **NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyle.None** then only **mouseDown** of image view is called. And if I don't give **selectionHighlightStyle** to **NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyle.None** then both **mouseDown** of imageview and **tableViewSelectionDidChange** are getting called. Setting **selectionHighlightStyle** to none seems to solve my problem but is this correct approch? Or I am getting this behaviour because of some bug in appkit?

Also I can't find this behaviour documented somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the correct approach you be to subclass NSTableView and override the NSResponder method `-(BOOL)validateProposedFirstResponder:(NSResponder *)responder forEvent:(NSEvent *)event`

You'll have a finer control over which view will get the mouse event, and won't have to resort to "hackery" like changing the table view selection style.

From the apple docs:

> Specifying How Subviews Should Respond to Events
>
> Views or controls in a table sometimes need to respond to incoming events. To determine whether a particular subview should receive the current mouse event, a table view calls validateProposedFirstResponder:forEvent: in its implementation of hitTest. If you create a table view subclass, you can override validateProposedFirstResponder:forEvent: to specify which views can become the first responder. In this way, you receive mouse events.
>
> The default NSTableView implementation of validateProposedFirstResponder:forEvent: uses the following logic:
>
> Return YES for all proposed first responder views unless they are instances or subclasses of NSControl.
> Determine whether the proposed first responder is an NSControl instance or subclass.
>
> If the control is an NSButton object, return YES.
>
> If the control is not an NSButton, call the control’s hitTestForEvent:inRect:ofView: to see whether the hit area is trackable (that is, NSCellHitTrackableArea) or is an editable text area (that is, NSCellHitEditableTextArea), and return the appropriate value. Note that if a text area is hit, NSTableView also delays the first responder action.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/RowSelection/RowSelection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000026i-CH6-SW9

Comment: Thanks. I subclasses it and returned true for my problem's condition. Works perfectly.